# sort unique urls from log

Tags: shell, sorting, logging, uniq

I need to get the unique URLs from a web log and then sort them. I was thinking of using grep, uniq, sort command and output this to another file

I executed this command:

```
cat access.log | awk '{print $7}' > url.txt
```

then only get the unique one and sort them:

```
cat url.txt | uniq | sort > urls.txt
```

The problem is that I can see duplicates, even though the file is sorted which means my command worked. Why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`uniq | sort` does not work: `uniq` removes contiguous duplicates.

The correct way is `sort | uniq` or better `sort -u`. Because only one process is spawned.

Answer (score 5):

uniq needs its input sorted, but you sorted after uniq.  Try:

```
$ sort -u < url.txt > urls.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
cat url.txt | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

For nginx access logs, this gives the unique URLs being called:

```
 sed -r "s/.*(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE|HEAD) (.*?) HTTP.*/\2/" /var/log/nginx/access.log | sort | uniq -u
```

Reference:
https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2008/08/10/generating-url-list-from-access-log-access_log/